# Product subselection

Tags: magento-2.1

In setting up a Cart Rule, I wanted to restrict the use of coupon code from a particular category. Meaning, products from all other categories can use the coupon, just not this particular one. It really confuses me because the below works:

```
If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :

    If total quantity  greater than  0  for a subselection of items in cart matching ALL  of these conditions: 
    Category  is  114
```

The category that I don't want the coupon to be able to be used for is 114. However, only with this rule did the effect works.

When I change it to

```
If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :

    If total quantity  greater than  0  for a subselection of items in cart matching ALL  of these conditions: 
    Category  is not  114
```

Suddenly I can use the coupon code for only products in category 114.

Is this a magento bug? I am using 2.1.5.

Answer (score 0):

Try to **select all parent categories** too, so clean cache and reindex:

```
alias mage="php -d memory_limit=-1 -f bin/magento"

chmod -R 775 pub/static/ var/ pub/media/ &&
rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/ var/cache/ var/page_cache/ var/tmp/ var/generation/ pub/static/frontend/ ;
mage cache:clean &
mage cache:flush &
mage indexer:reindex
```

Comment: 777 sounds bad.

Comment: @Calvintwr changed to 775